# Dynamically generated Javascript input fields are not recognized by Httpservletrequest??? ONLY in Chrome?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am trying to do a multipart upload where the input type of file is dynamically generated.
Later i include all my field forms in to bean through httpservlet request.
But when i iterate i cant find the dynamic input fields generated through javascript only in chrome!!!..

```
<table id="table1" name="table1">
                <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                </tr>
                </table>


 function add()
  {
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var cnt=rowCount
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type="checkbox";
    element1.name="selectbx_"+cnt;
    element1.id='selectbx_'+cnt;
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type="text";
    element2.name="Description_"+cnt;
    element2.id="Description_"+cnt;
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type="file";
    element3.size="25";
    element3.name="Attachment"+cnt;
    element3.id="Attachment"+cnt;
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
  }
```

finally on submit i am doing a 
mybeanobject.map(request.getParameterMap());
mybeanobject.map(request);

Any ideas why?

Comment: ... But when i iterate i cant find the dynamic input fields... how do you iterate... code example?

Comment: @R.Oosterholt : i get the httpservletrequest and iterate it like List upload_items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator itr = upload_items.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
upload_item = (FileItem)itr.next();      
      }
      if(upload_item.isFormField())
{
key = upload_item.getFieldName();
val= upload_item.getString();

Comment: are the newly added elements in the dom (use inspector) and are they inside the form element somewhere?

Comment: @R.Oosterholt no they are not inside form tag but a dynamic javascript event on button click..

Comment: do you use form's submit (submit button or js submit())?

Answer (score 1):

Only elements inside a form tab are submitted.
Add the dynamically elements to the document somewhere inside the form Element.

Comment: I have the javascript in head section inside <script></script> .Is that not enough?? shoulg i need to put the script inside<form></form>?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the script which generates the element, as long as you generate the element in the correct place in the dom. They should be inside the form element.

Comment: Yes..they are generated in the correct place but cant be viewed in viewsource since they are generated dynamically..neither javascript nor jquery!!

Comment: ... but cant be viewed in viewsource ... Correct, not in view source. You should use a dev tool. In chrome there is one build-in, in Firefox you can use firebug and in IE you can use the dev tool...

Comment: Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools.
Dev tools are a must-have for javascript development...

Comment: i found the issue.. when i submit the form i take all the form parameters through mybeanobject.map(request.getParameterMap()) and when i iterate through this request i couldn't find the dynamically generated javascript input fields ONLY IN CHROME AND FIREFOX , IE works fine...Any suggestions??

Comment: did you use a dev tool to check whether or not the elements are inside  the form element somewhere?

Comment: Well not sure why IE works (huh? IE works?), but the elements should be somewhere inside the form element to be posted on submit...